# Possibly bad review audit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, disputed-review-audits, triage, specific-audit

I was reviewing the Triage, when I came through [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/23717625).

It **does not** show any attempt to **solve the problem**, and the question itself isn't too clear (it was mentioned in the comments as well), so I've **flagged it for closure**.

Then, it told to me, that this is a good post. Currently it has 5 votes, and that's why it can be an audit, but *should* this post be an audit?

OK, it's possible, that it shouldn't be closed, but as an audit, it very confusing. Please tell me, am I right?

Comment: @gnat come on. That might be something you can link as relevant, but it is in no way a duplicate. That's a really trollish way to discourage users from participating and you know that. Please stop closing new meta questions as duplicates of tangentially related questions. Duplicate closure is for duplicates **only**

Comment: Much like specific-question tagged questions are only duplicates if they ask about the same question, duplicate bad review audits are only the same if they refer to the same audit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*This answer is based on a comment by TylerH.*

This is indeed a terrible question, but perhaps one that has been saved by [very good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57038268/2751851). I think it's a case where the OP should be expected to improve it rather than one of us. I don't think it is an appropriate Triage audit (usually audits are more black and white), and an exemption should probably be made for it.

If possible, try to contact a moderator about this and see if they can get this audit removed from the Review Queue.

Comment: Yet another example of people potentially being put off reviewing by the current awful audit system. Why not only present audit questions where existing reviewers have been unanimous in a particular direction?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I removed the stub template because this answer is now complete.

Comment: @JL2210 What changed to make it complete? The text is identical to the text when the stub tag was initially added.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy See revision 2.

Comment: @JL2210 Hmmm... don't really consider changing the attribution line really something that would take it from a stub to a well formed answer. But whatever.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Look more carefully.

Comment: @JL2210 If that is all that was needed, then the stub tag was never really needed. The answer never changed in a material way. simply grammar changes or a link to something that was already mentioned without a link is not something that will take a 'partial' answer to a full answer. Seems like much ado about nothing if that is all that's trying to be accomplished. I would have expected at least a paragraph of new text at a minimum.

Comment: We don't need mention of a stub in the answer. The fact it is a CW is enough to know it can be improved upon by the community. Can meta please just stop fighting for a day?

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely not the best question and can be improved. On the other hand, the site engine collects questions for audit based on formal criteria. I looked at the timeline. It seems to me that the question met the criteria at the time of being added to the queue (and even at the time of the review). There is nothing that the dev team can do here. I retagged the question. If you have any objections, please let me know.