# Banned from reviewing suddenly and silently - why?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-suspension

Yesterday I've reviewed some posts, without problems. Today, the review page **didn't** said that I've reviewed too much post incorrectly (with a link to a failed audit), instead, only the following:

> #### Review
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23506658
>
> Come back on Oct 11 at 22:21 to continue reviewing.

The link points to a suggested edit, which I've approved (Not an audit!)

In the past few days, I've really falied a (bad) audit, see my post about it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388166/8376184), but it didn't triggered a review ban. Since it I haven't failed.

So, I don't know why did this happen. Is this a bug, or something I intended, that I didn't know about?

Comment: A review ban is never "reasonlessly", and __very__ unlikely to be a bug... A review ban that doesn't come from an audit is usually put in place by a moderator.

Comment: The edit introduced spam. See the user's profile (they're also suspended now). `utm[...]=stackoverflow[.com]` is usually a bad sign btw. The review suspension is correct though - you should've been more alert to a user introducing that link. A moderator created the ban from what I can tell

Comment: @Zoe But... why is that a spam? The links look like related to the post..

Comment: @FZs: The fact that a low rep user is adding links to another user's post is _always_ a red flag. Reason enough to have a look at the user's profile, which would've told you he's spamming.

Comment: @FZs if I went ahead and created a blog and posted an article related to an answer, and edited in the link, wouldn't that still be spam? It's a spam edit - it doesn't make the answer spam, but it's enough to reject the edit (or, if it's a high-rep user, roll back and mod-flag)

Comment: The user that suggested the edit for whose review you were suspended has himself been suspended for a week for spamming.

Comment: see also: [Is there a specific penalty for suggested edit spam? Should I do anything about it other than rejecting it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360812/839601) "if you find users approving them, do flag them as well, we'll send them off the review queues for a small amount of time..."

Comment: A note for those who don’t want to follow the link in the edit: the about page for the first site makes it clear the blog belongs to the user making the edits.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you can see if you visit that post, the edit was rolled back manually by a moderator, likely because the edit was considered inappropriate.

It's perfectly acceptable for a moderator to manually suspend you from edit review if you accept inappropriate edits.

That leaves us with the question: *Why* was this edit inappropriate?

Well, it edited links to off-site resources into someone elses answer, while these links were not directly related to the answer. That's not a good edit for many reasons, including the risk of spam, link-rot, it looks like the author of the answer endorsed these links, and it's likely against the authors intent. A fine reason imo to roll it back.

Be *very* hesitant to accept edits that add or change links, especially links that don't point to official resources. These are rarely good edits.

Comment: So, in the future, should I reject these edits 'automatically', even if the links look like related?

Comment: Remember you can always "skip".

Comment: @FZs See Cerbrus's comment (he forgot to "ping" you). Also, generally, accepting edits to Answers is very tricky. Often, what's edited in should be in its own answer, rather than changing what the Answer OP writes. Correcting spelling or very bad grammar errors is OK. Correcting links that have gone bad *can* be OK. Changing anything in code except a really obvious error is **not** OK. Adding content is border-line, sometimes OK but more often not. If you're not sure, SKIP.

Comment: @FZs Imo pretty much yes. If you're unsure you can hit skip, but unless the edit is in line with the existing answer (e.g. a link added to a list of links to all versions of a specific resource), there's no need to go editing links into existing answers. The editor could've posted the link as a comment (dubious, but it's at least more clear who added the link when), or written his own answer incorporating/summarizing + linking the relevant content he found. Then ownership and voting is more clear

Comment: @FZs What can you can so in case you come across someone editing links, is to go to the "SO close vote review chat" and ask there if they think it is spam. Getting rid of spammers is important, far more so than reviewing edits. If you aren't certain, you can also flag suspected spam with a custom reason "I suspect this is spam but I'm not certain. Can a moderator investigate?" or similar. But it is better to ask the review veterans in that chat room first, before bothering the moderators.

Comment: @Lundin that's great advice and honestly the mods don't mind people raising these types of flags, it would save us all a lot of time in many instances than to ignore the addition of links to an answer. Also the reviewer can go and see the other suggested edits made by that editor.

Comment: cc @FZs ...........^^

Answer (score 16):

I review banned you.

There was a custom flag on the editor to review their edits and the reviewers. This happens frequently.

You approved an [edit introducing self promotion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360810/is-there-a-specific-penalty-for-suggested-edit-spam-should-i-do-anything-about) into a post. You've been review banned 7 times in total and need to learn how to review.

I spent several hours checking the suggested editors edits and rejecting or rolling most of them back and manually banning the reviewers.

Honestly, every time I have to manually review ban a user I'm imposing a harsher penalty than the [automatic review ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/3956566). I go one or two up from the automatic recommended ban. Why? Because it is painfully time consuming to fix it and reviewers need to do their jobs properly or be prevented from wasting everyone's time. No reviewer is better than a poor reviewer.